# Unity - Parenting an object hides it

Tags: unity-game-engine, hide

I am trying to parent some objects but when I do so, it hides them and my game doesn't render them.
any help?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4eCnS.png)

Answer (score 0):

To correctly parent an object to another, you will need to consider a few things:

**1-** The parent object must be active and visible, so its child objects are visible too.

**2-** The parent must not interfere in the fundamental components of its child's objects like `Mesh Render`, Objects visibility, or whatever reason that can cause the child to become invisible.

Answer (score 0):

The scale of your parent object `Map` is `0` in the x axis. Changing it to `1` is likely to solve the problem.